# Increasing ulimit on CentOS

Tags: centos, ulimit

We have a CentOS box that I'm trying to increase the max number of files that a user can have open.  Currently when I run `ulimit -Sn` I get `1024` and `ulimit -Hn` gives `4096`.  I need that number up around 6000.

In `/etc/sysctl.conf` I've set `fs.file-max = 100000`.  In `/etc/security/limits.conf` I have the following set:

```
username soft nofile 6000
username hard nofile 65535
```

I've logged out and logged back in as `username` but am still not seeing my changes.  What do I need to get this value changed?

All I have in `/etc/security/limits.d` is `90-nproc.conf`.  I've also ensured that ulimit is not being called in my .bash_profile or .bashrc.

When I run `sysctl -p` it spits out the settings I want and it shows the value for `fs.file-max` that I want.  But when I run `ulimit -Sn`, I get 1048.  If I try to run `sysctl --system` I get `error: Unknown parameter "--system"`.

Comment: Did you try to reboot? As far as I know those settings are read during system boot.

Comment: You don't need a reboot for that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To force `/etc/sysctl.conf` to be read again run `sysctl -p`.

File `/etc/security/limits.conf` is read by login shells and you should close active sessions windows if in GUI. For remote logins, it takes effect on relog.

Comment: Ran that, still not seeing changes after a relog.

Comment: @tubaguy50035 `fs.file-max` is the max number of open file on the system. It's a hard limit and it won't be reflected by `ulimit` calls in your case.

Comment: Oh, okay.  Should I not be running into too many files open anymore then?

Comment: @tubaguy50035 Not related. It's the system hard limit that will override any number above in limits.conf. But limits.conf is still what's applied. Could you try to set the hard & soft limits with ulimit directly in a new session and see if you get same maximums? Something seems to override your configuration.

Comment: It says operation is not permitted.  Do I need to give the user access to something?  I'd rather the web user not have root privileges.

Comment: @tubaguy50035 Try to change the soft limit. You can't change the hard limit if you aren't root.

Comment: Ah okay.  I can change the soft limit.  The hard limit is still lower than I'm setting at 4096.  How can I change that for my user?

Comment: @tubaguy50035 What's set with ulimit is only temporary, that was for testing purposes. It will get reset on relog. You likely have something overriding your configuration somewhere, try to find the value somewhere on the filesystem.

Comment: I've run a grep on the entire file system.  4096 is not a unique value!  But I don't see anywhere where it deals with this issue.  There's a lot in the boot/config stuff, but it seems to all be dealing with allocation of memory limits.

Answer (score 9):

As another poster has said, you need to have sysctl set the value in the running kernel.  There are several ways you can set the value without rebooting:

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -w fs.file-max=100000
sysctl --system
```

IMHO the last method is the best, as it replicates the order that the settings would be applied during boot (and thus if you have a conflict it will become apparent).

Note: I'm not sure which version of CentOS you're using, but on 7 at least I have run into a problem where if dracut rebuilds the initramfs for any reason (such as when installing a new kernel module) it will copy over the contents of /etc/sysctl.* into the initramfs, which will then be executed by systemd-sysctl during that phase, even if you later delete those entries out of /etc/sysctl.conf.

In my environment I've edited the systemd dracut module to exclude /etc/sysctl.* from that environment (as those settings will get set once the rootfs is mounted and systemd-sysctl runs again).  It's just a gotcha that you might run into.

Comment: I'm on CentOS 6.5.  Also updated my question with results of some of that.